# floating div with different size

Tags: css, html

I wrote below code to display 3 divs in a 600x400 container, but got below problem. Please help.

```
<DIV A style="float:left;width:200px;;height:200px;"></DIV>
<DIV B style="float:left;width:400px;;height:400px;"></DIV>
<DIV C style="float:left;width:200px;;height:200px;"></DIV>
```

[image: Problem description]

Comment: user 2 columns for this.

Comment: ohk ... so my understanding of float was wrong. thanks ...

Answer (score 5):

Instead you need to float a container that contains the two smaller divs, a-la:

```
<div style="float:left">
    <div style=";width:200px;;height:200px;"></DIV>
    <div style="float:left;width:200px;;height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/r7b7e/

If A and C are both floated, they won't wrap anyway unless the width of the container is small enough to make them wrap.  However, the container (of all three divs) also needs to include the larger div, which makes that impossible.  Instead you  need to wrap them in their own container.

Comment: hmm ... my idea was floated divs should act like elastics, always try to fill the adjacent void .. obviously I was wrong.... I have to re-write whole design again :( ..... Thanks anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` B should be `float: right;`